# Button for "Play, but from beginning" for a scrubber UX

Tags: buttons, icons, symbols, interactive-ui

Consider a typical video-editing style timeline:

There's the usual Play button: a right arrow.

There's the usual Pause button: two bars.

```
-----------------|-----------
         >  ||
```

However, I want to have a **"Play, but from beginnning"** button.

When you want to "play, but from the beginning" you have to: bring the slider to the beginning, before hitting play. That is annoying. It would be better if there was a "play, but from the beginning" button.

What should the symbol be?

Help me out gang!

---

Lame idea from non-designer...

[image]

Does that get anyone thinking? It's not really very good: the one on the left probably suggests *"cycle around in some sense"* It's hard to express "go back to the frickin' beginning and then Play"!

---

*Complication:* most editors additionally have a "Play, but fullscreen" concept, yet another play-related button.

*Bonus:* If there's a keyboard, space-bar usually toggles Play/Pause.  Is there a good keyboard UX for "Play from beginning"?

Comment: [The Noun Project: “Replay”](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=replay&i=72013)

Comment: For me "Replay" is a different concept than "Move scrubber to start, and Play".  It's tricky!

Comment: Logic uses the return key to "return" to the start of the song. From memory, Sonar uses the "w" key. I used to say "wewind" to remind me... Return makes more sense, to me.

Comment: Good thinking on Return ... but that more says "go to start" to me, rather than "go to start, and, play"... great info thx

Comment: Since you already presumably have a "play from current position" button, have you ever considered just adding a "rewind to beginning" button? If already playing it continues playing otherwise it just sits there. With a keyboard shortcut for both the sequence becomes very convenient. Your current strategy of "play from beginning" still requires the "rewind" button anyways; your "play from beginning" is really just a convenience of two otherwise available functions.

Comment: Hi Jason, as mentioned numerously .. consider the case that you're sitting there paused (head not moving).  Am looking for one-touch, rather than two-touch, to achieve "Head to start + run".  It is a most common thing in the application.  This is for glass (although I mentioned keyboard combo as a curiosity, for on "computers"!)

Comment: @JoeBlow  To keep with your theme your best bet then is to combine the two icons you're already using for play / rewind. That would intuitively suggest to a user that the button is the combination of those other two actions. What are your current icons for those two functions?

Comment: (I notice you mention that you just have the user touch the scrub slider to rewind. It's up to you but you might want to reconsider. Getting a slider all the way to the left almost always requires even a short drag. And if rendering performance is low and the short drag happens to take the user over other earlier frames, you have to be sure your implementation does not hang up the slider while scrolling to stay responsive. It's almost impossible to click the far left of a slider without dragging at least a little.)

Comment: Whatever the chosen solution, it needs verification by user testing. My best guess is that a dedicated visual control isn’t necessary and all suggested icons will be either opaque or misleading/ambiguous to some actual users, even if they’re accustomed to AV editing software GUIs. (I remember Cool Edit, for instance, where the usual triangle played just the current selection and there was a circled one for playing the whole track.) I think you’re better off if you make _playing_ a state instead of _play/pause_ an action, or you provide a power-user feature through long tap / double click / …

Comment: Hi Jason, I completely agree with your point about "click difficulties" on scrubbers.

Comment: "your best bet then is to combine the two icons you're already using for play / rewind" I'm inclined to believe that is a sensible solution. Maybe you should show it as an ansswer here?

Comment: The play button should always play from the beginning. The pause button should pause playback and then with another press, play from the current position. I think you are starting from the mindset of a combination play/pause button and then trying to invent a second “play from the beginning” button to deal with the fact that the play and pause buttons have been combined. Just separate the play and pause buttons and use them traditionally.

Comment: @SimonWhite Hmm - you make an excellent point.  However, "The play button should always play from the beginning" unfortunately much software does it "as discussed on this page so far" you know?  separate buttons.. But yes your point is excellent and it's amazing nobody mentioned this yet really - fascinating  :O

Comment: I was going to say *Icon Questions* are blatantly off-topic on this site, but seeing this question has so many votes... well, good riddance

Comment: I need to ask, why do you need a dedicated button and just ignore the scrubber's functionality?

Comment: Hi Majo - indeed, in the particular app in question it is a particularly common function.  You're paused in the middle somewhere: you want to either play, or, reset-to-start-and-play.  As others have mentioned I agree it's *usually* not desirable (generally I am against complex, multi-function, buttons, as you probably are: here it's something you do all the time).

Comment: @JoeBlow interested to find out what you decide to implement from all these suggestions once you make the decision.

Comment: @JoeBlow search 'restart play' on the link Crissov posted in the comments https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=restart+play

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with many around here that it is possibly best to stick with the icons that are so common for media players.

However I understand the problem you try to solve. Mixing both icons could be a nice solution. But as always; testing is knowing!

My attempt for a possible mix:
[image]

And to emphasize that it starts from the beginning...

Add a line:
[image]

Or use different alignment:
[image]

Indeed you only need this:

[image]

Comment: WOW - WHAT A GREAT IDEA!

Comment: I note also that, simply repeating the `Play` icon, *but having it at the left edge*, may be the very best solution!  So, there's the usual group of three "in the middle", BUT the dual-function button under discussion here is simply *at the left edge* of the scrubber. Oh wow.  Facepalm --- so obvious once you say it.

Comment: @JoeBlow A second play button can be confusing, I would make the one on the left at least a bit different just to highlight they are not exactly the same. Or if resume playing is used rarely you can remove the middle button entirely.

Comment: Right - there should be a small arrow or something, from the left-play button.

Comment: @JoeBlow, you're welcome and thank you for the reward!

Answer (score 78):

## v1

I would suggest that the play button stays the same as it always has - a triangle to begin then a pause once playback begins. But, once playback *has* started, a new button appears like this:

[image]

The circle encapsulating the easily recognisable play triangle is pointing in an intuitive direction: anti-clockwise, implying that we are going back in time. The button as a whole still means *play* but we use the arrow to infer a different meaning.

[image]

---

## v2

As suggested by **JoeBlow** in the comments below, here is a second version using a semi-circle shape to "jump" back to the start:

[image]

I like the idea here, but as has been remarked it might look a little odd centering the icon vertically. But given the correct context, I think its pretty clear what it is representing as per the following example:

[image]

---

## v3

Here is one more example that draws from a previous effort...

[image]

...but wasn't well received:

[image]

The evolution of the previous version to this one looks a lot like one of Crissov's examples in his answer, which again adds weight to the representation of this design.

[image]

---

## v4

Here's one last example that places the controls on the timeline. Its a bit of fun more than anything else, but the icons flow with the timeline, interrupt the timeline or redirect it. It is quite a departure from normal conventions, but an enjoyable thought experiment nonetheless.

[image]

## Example Usage

KRyan in the comments asked for a usage scenario so here is an example mocked up with YouTube.

This is how the video interface looks before a video starts playing:

[image]

Once the video starts playing the Play button we see above changes to a pause button. I'm proposing that an additional button (once playback starts) could slide in, allowing you to jump back to the beginning. Like this:

[image]

Comment: That semi-circle arrow button is outstanding!

Comment: While from a pure logical standpoint the half-circle play button makes more sense than the full-circle youtube version or full-circle play button at the top of this answer, I believe the full-circle is more intuitive as it is tried and true and used in many applications to mean restart. Not saying the half circle couldn't work but this may be a situation where not reinventing the wheel (or circle) is better.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35257/discussion-on-answer-by-chris-spittles-button-for-play-but-from-beginning-for).

Comment: V1 is pretty good. V2 is OK. V3 is _confusing_! It looks like some combination of "Eject" (due to the triangle-and-bar icon) and "Play and loop continuously" (due to the oval being connected to the arrow tip and tail).

Comment: I've seen v3 or something a lot like that on tape-decks.

Comment: I read all three of them as: play, then reset to start, which is not what they are supposed to mean. The icon suggested by the OP seems to be much more intuitively.

Comment: In the context of video (or audio) editing, I would interpret a play button with a full circle around it as "play, and automatically loop when reaching the end". I don't know if that's just my intuition, but I would try to avoid that possibility of confusion.

Answer (score 35):

IEC 60417 is a standard for symbols to put on electrical devices (TVs, VCRs, washing machines, MRIs etc.) and ISO 7000 collects these. Each costs around 100 bucks, but there is a [free preview PDF](https://webstore.iec.ch/webstore/webstore.nsf/404?ReadForm).
It’s the closest I could find that would standardize the [common playback controls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_controls) like *play* ▶️, *pause* ⏸, *play/pause* ⏯, *stop* ⏹, *fast forward* ⏩, *rewind* ⏪, *skip/next* ⏭, *prev* ⏮, *record* ⏺.
It covers all of these and more.

The standard even offers two variants for many of the media control icons.
Alas, the symbols in actual use are rather a mix of both, e.g. the equivalent of *playback* in the standard #5107A/B: *Normal run; Normal speed* is either an arrow with a hollow equilateral triangle as head ⇾ or a filled isosceles triangle ►, whereas commonly a filled equilateral triangle ▶ is used (all pointing right).

[image: ⇾] or [image: ►]

Likewise, the symbol ↪️ #5125 ***Recapitulate*** has two variants A/B:

[image] and [image: ↪︎]

They both follow the example of #5862 *Previous; Play previous part*, which looks quite distinct from ⏭ #5861 *Next; Play next part*:

[image: ↪|] vs. [image: ⏭]

Those come both in a single variant, but are based upon the different *Normal run* variants. Standards – go figure.

I obviously don’t recommend to follow standards blindly, especially when they obviously have been adapted with a bit of freedom by the industry. (Other parts of the standards are followed slavishly in respective areas, though.) Also, as I’ve shown, the standard symbols don’t seem to be consistent all the time.

My actual suggestion would be to use an #5459 *Eject* symbol ⏏ turned a quarter-circle clock-wise, filled or hollow as fits the visual scheme.
Reasoning: The vertical bar on the left then indicates an earlier cue mark, which is the start of the current track by default.
There’s a similar IEC symbol #5471 *Frame by frame, general* with two thin lines.
Note that the more familiar variant of ⏸ #5111B *Pause; Interruption* is just as hollow as the triangles (or the *Stop* square).

[image: ⏏] ⤵︎ [image: turned eject: replay, play again, play from start, recapitulate] ≈ [image: ⏸▶️] ≠ [image: ⏸]

PS: The ISO/IEC 9995-7 standard symbol for the [Home key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_key) is ⇱.

### Related standards

I didn’t actually review any of these in detail, but provide them for reference:

- ISO/IEC 18035  *Icon symbols and functions for controlling multimedia software applications* This one seems very appropriate, in section 6 it specifies:

  1. Dynamic media controls (*Play, Stop, Pause, Replay, Play backward, Scan forward, Scan backward, Fast forward, Rewind, Step forward, Step backward, Record*)
  2. Attributes of dynamic media controls (*Loop, Set volume, Mute, Speaker on*)
  3. Navigation controls (*Go to … beginning, previous state / visited presentation segment / media object, next presentation segment within the application / media object within the composite media object, end / exit*)
  4. Additional controls (*Main menu, Eject, Help, Snapshot, Save*)
- ISO 14915-2 *Software ergonomics for multimedia user interfaces — Part 2: Multimedia navigation and control* This standard is more about the concepts than the symbols.

More general ones:

- ISO/IEC 11581-1, -6  *User system interfaces and symbols — Icon symbols and functions — Part 1: Icons — General* Not about multimedia control, this standard deals with common icons for office and generic applications, e.g. *Open, Save, Print, Bold*.
- ISO 14915-1 *Software ergonomics for multimedia user interfaces — Part 1: Design principles and framework*
- ISO 9241-12, -13, -16 *Ergonomic requirements for office work with visual display terminals (VDTs)*

  - *Part 12: Presentation of information*
  - *Part 13: User guidance*
  - *Part 16: Direct manipulation dialogues*

### Examples from actual products

[image: Apple Logic Pro X]
[image: Microsoft Powerpoint for Mac (presenter view)]
[image: Adobe Premiere Pro]
<sub>(source: [adobe.com](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/playing-assets/_jcr_content/main-pars/procedure_2/proc_par/step_0/step_par/image.img.png/playback.png))</sub>

Comment: This is absolutely incredible info.

Comment: Do we know what **Recapitulate** means?  If I try to translate the symbol, for me it means: *"Run from the **end** to the **beginning** and then **keep running** and finally **stop where we are now**"*  Is that right????

Comment: @JoeBlow As it turns out, there’s a [shop for individual symbols](https://gnbs.isolutions.iso.org/obp/ui#iec:grs:60417:0:5125A) which has previews and further info: “To identify the control or the indicator which permits rapid access within a recorded programme to repeat the section which has just been played.”

Comment: [Westheimer’s Discovery](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Frank_Westheimer): “A couple of months in the laboratory can frequently save a couple of hours in the library” and I’d like to add “… or a few minutes around the water cooler.”

Comment: Ah - recapitulation - interesting.  So, not really "go to start; play"... (unless, you just did that!  :) )

Comment: @JoeBlow "recapitulate", as a word, means "to repeat the principal stages or phases of", "to restate", etc. You probably don't want to use that word exactly in your UI because it's meaning may not be commonly known ("play from beginning" would be clearer) but it's an accurate term for the effect.

Comment: Hi Jason!  As you say, in general English recapitulate means to "present a summary of", to "state the main points of". For me, recapitulate when dealing with an editor would mean "redo, the stuff what I just did". Or essentially "Bring up a summary of the project" (or "..of what I just did.") I'm sure you're **correct** that in that PDF document, the PDF authors meant it to mean what we're discussing here ("rewind to start; and; hit play"), I don't think it's a good use of the word. Anyway it's by the by, I wouldn't be using that word for any particular reason in the UX  :)

Comment: BTW perhaps just **"Play All"** is the quickest way to express the concept at hand, maybe

Comment: the first few reminded me heavily of diodes :-)

Answer (score 34):

you can use a restart / reset  button, here's an example from YouTube, the leftmost button
[image]

Comment: Hmmm!  Thanks - crap, I don't know if I like that symbol.  For me it means "loop" or something .... tricky one ...

Comment: What is a "restart / reset button" ?

Comment: @JoeBlow the leftmost button in the picture

Comment: I've got you now -- you know, I don't know if that symbol is a success!  For me it means something like "loop".  For example, say we are at 30% and paused.  For me that button means "play from 30% in a loop and go around until you get to 30% again and stop".  It does not mean, for my mind, "go back to the start, then, play to the end".  It's not a good symbol, to my thinking!

Comment: also, this youtube feature is only displayed after a video has finished playing, while the video is still playing the symbol stays the standard "Play"  triangle

Comment: @JowBlow That's a fair assessment, but my hunch is that the majority of people would not come that conclusion. The idea of that button meaning "loop from the beginning back to the current time repeatedly" sounds like something a more technical person would think of. That doesn't mean it's wrong, just a hunch.

Comment: First time I saw this on YouTube I knew exactly what it mean, probably because it does not appear until the video has reached the end, so maybe  you can also do it like that if you use this button, hide it until when it can actually be of use

Comment: For what it's worth, when I see that circle-arrow, by default I think "refresh" - as in, refresh the page (which would presumably then resume playing the video from the current point). Seems that it would be worth looking into how intuitive it is to associate this symbol with the desired meaning.

Answer (score 14):

Traditionally, the 'previous button' is used. 1 click returns to the beginning of the clip, and a double click goes to the beginning of the previous clip. Holding could also jog back.

[image: Previous Button]

Comment: Hi Sameul - for me that icon means "move to beginning".  What I want is, say we are paused at 40%, I want a DOUBLE action .. "move to beginning" AND "and then Play".  BTW that's a great "iconic" example of "move to the beginning" .. did you find that somewheres or make it?

Comment: @JoeBlow It looks like the one from Spotify. I was just about to post it as an alternate solution.

Comment: @JoeBlow As a user, I would be surprised if this button stopped playing the video. The onyl case I would expect it to not do so is if I had explicitly paused the media (which I consider to be a special case where I have explicit set the state and the player is honoring that). Why would I want the media to stop just because I threw it back to the beginning?

Comment: Indeed!  I want a new button that means, and you're probably currently paused, "go to start; and then Play"

Comment: @JoeBlow Sounds very non-standard. How much value does that button provide over simply letting them unpause it after moving back to the beginning? Because it's going to cost screen space and the user is going to have to think more about all the options they have.

Comment: it saves you a click.  In the product at hand, it's an extremely common operation, so it is very useful.  I appreciate what you mean *generally* - normally I'm highly in favor of having as few buttons as possible.

Comment: I dislike this button and avoid using it, because I can never be sure whether clicking on it is going to go back to the beginning of the current whatever, or go back to the beginning of the *previous* whatever (at which point returning to the current whatever may be difficult).

Comment: @PixelSnader Yes, this example is from spotify. 

 In nearly all of my music and video editing programs, this button returns to the beginning, as well as plays.
Spotify, Ableton, MediaComposer, and ProTools all do this action.

Comment: EDIT: In ProTools, playing after move to zero is a setting in Preferences. 

Either way, I think playing or not playing can be an application setting, and does not require a new logo. Just be consistent.

Comment: +1 for this idea. Expected behavior is most likely: "move to beginning and do not change playing state": so if the video is playing, continue playing, if not, do not start playing. In some apps (I think Music or Podcast or Spotify on iOS) the behavior of this button is "smart": during the first x seconds of the video, single tap skips to the start of the previous video/ song; and if the scrubber is farther ahead, single tap skips to beginning of current video/ song. This has additional bonus that repeatedly single-tapping always has each single tap skip back one song..

Comment: For reference, this is how iOS Podcast and Music apps handle the concept of “play from beginning”

Answer (score 6):

> Play .. play from "where the head is now". We're still in edit
>   concept.

You need to use the icon that has to toggle between pause and play, something like [image: this]

> However, I want to have a "Play, but from beginnning" button.

Try this icon for simply restarting from the beginning.
[image]

> Try .. Leave edit concept (so, things could happen like "widgets
>   disappear from screen" "we go to full screen" or whatever), and play
>   from beginning to end; at end, likely revert to edit concept.

If something has been edited, just show a checkbox `Check this to save on Play`. If user doesn't select it, then changes will be lost.

Comment: Good point to combine play-pause.  With the circle-arrow ---- that's two votes!  Maybe I'm wrong!  I don't like it for some reason guys!! :O

Comment: @JoeBlow Sorry, but your comment is bit confusing. Did you liked the icon or not? and why?

Comment: hi man ... I'm not a fan of the "circle-arrow" to mean "go to beginning, and play".  Note my long comments on this, in the other answers... (Your answer is excellent, I'm just not a fan of that icon)

Comment: @JoeBlow I have updated the image, please check it out. I disagree though that circle-arrow is bad, since I think it does the job on Youtube pretty convincingly. Though this new android one is better.

Comment: You know, I don't like the youtube one!! to me it means "loop", or something.  (Indeed it took me ages to figure out what it meant when it appeared on youtube back when: to be clear, when i asked this question I had clean forgotten about it.)

Comment: This is not about a hardware device, so the icon ⏯ can switch dynamically between Play ▶️ and Pause ⏸. Actually, the single vertical bar to the left of a right-pointing triangle icon is what I would suggest for _play from start_! (It’s found neither in Unicode emoji nor [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/#video-player), the most similar one would be an arrow ➡️.) One could use a normal triangle and a circled triangle (see Font Awesome), where the circle indicated wholeness. The arrow re-cycle is for Reload as an action or Repeat All as a mode.

Comment: Your idea of **SINGLE BAR PLUS TRIANGLE** seems to be a superb idea.  Your answer here so far is "just" encyclopaedic (what already exists), what you just said is a superb idea.  Is there anything like that currently or can one of you geniuses make it to get the ball rolling?

Answer (score 6):

How about this.. It shows 00:00 , meaning the beginning of the clip. This probably IMO is easiest to understand for a general user.. without using loop symbols etc.

[image]

Edited based on comment from Crissov.

Comment: Triangle pointing left conventionally means play at single speed in reverse direction in media control buttons.

Comment: CLEVER.   could there just be a "zero" in there maybe.  VERY CLEVER IDEA

Comment: Sure. I thought about zero only.. as display. But 00:00 made more sense and users might relate more to that I felt.

Comment: An icon with that sort of detail would only work well at large sizes. It would not translate well to a smaller icon.

Comment: The idea here is "play triangle with something in it".  Could it be something ELSE in it?  Like "play triangle with a small left-arrow in it" say?  It's a great idea to put something IN the play triangle, IMO.

Comment: Nathan K is correct. It might not be really practical to have this translate into a small icon. But as Joe Blow pointed out, thats the basic idea, we could have something shorter/smaller in place of 00:00.. may be 0.

Comment: i LOVE the interior-sub-icon concept.  **I just stumbled on a great example of it**

Comment: Please share what it is.. good luck.

Answer (score 5):

As this is a take on the skip back control which is a standard media playing control. You could incorporate a progressive disclosure icon into that skip backwards icon. When held the additional options would appear.

### Example:

- When **single clicked** the main action would initiate i.e. normal skip to start and would stay paused if currently paused.
- When **tap/clicked and held down**, a menu of additional options would appear which would include your skip back and play option. You then hover across and release on your option of choice or tap if touch screen.

### Rest state:

[image]

### When held down:

[image]

---

### Inspiration

This little arrow in the corner can be seen in programs like Photoshop/Illustrator. I've also seen it in Apple Xcode on the Run app button, when held Test, Profile and Analyse also appear as options. As Run is the predominant action in Xcode this has the main prominence, the other 3 actions are less common but still accessible when clicked and held.

Comment: this is a GREAT suggestion - I never thought about incorporating the "context menu corner arrow" in this issue ....

Answer (score 5):

So many good ideas here... I think the most intuitive ones incorporate the concept of the scrubber/timeline combined with the play button. Here's my take:

[image: play button and scrubber]

EDIT: A refined version...

[image]

This is a fascinating exercise. Great question.

Comment: ah hah! that is the only really "diagrammatically correct" icon!!!

Comment: For the "other" Ply ("play from where I am now), you could actually have a dynamic icon which moves the head marker to where you are now.  Sweet.

Comment: I feel this is the only icon concept mentioned that literally includes the notion "head position, start"

Comment: I feel this is the hugely ingenious "icon concept"; and PK2016 is ingenious for raising the "inside-icon-qualifiers" concept (à la Apple); and the answer by jazZRo is just brilliant (it has that "so obvious once you think of it" quality!)

Answer (score 4):

In products that play multiple items (videos, songs, etc.), you often have skip buttons, with icons like these:

[image: |<] [image: >|]

In theory, these are used to navigate between items.

In practice, skip backwards more often means "go to the beginning of the current item, and if we're already there, go to the beginning of the previous item instead."  You could eliminate the "if we're already there" part and just use it for "go to the beginning."

Comment: By all means, `|<` or sometimes `<<` means go back to the extreme left of the scrubber.  (Of course, sometimes `<<` and `>>` mean, "skim" aka "fast forward".)  In fact, I would usually have a button that says just that, **"Go back to the extreme left and just sit there."**.  But what I am looking for is "Go back to the extreme left, and then go ahead an Play - to save me clicking two separate buttons!*

Comment: @JoeBlow: I've seen some products immediately start playing after you skip back.  I've seen others remain paused.  I don't think this is well-established one way or the other, so you might be able to get away with this.

Comment: OK, TBC I will have a "skip to left end and do nothing" button (also "skip to right end and do nothing"), and of course Play, AND I want to have "skip to left end, and, also Play"

Comment: @JoeBlow: You may want to ask yourself whether the increased convenience is worth the increased complexity.  Those buttons are very similar in functionality, and you may have a cognitive load problem if you provide a lot of similar but not quite identical buttons throughout your interface.  But if this is the only instance, it may be fine.

Comment: Hi Kevin ..I absolutely agree with you.  Normally I trade "slightly more clicks" for "far greater simplicity".  Indeed, I'm a great believe in the "new" approach of "more and simpler buttons".  I can't stand paging through menus and stuff.  Anyway, in this particular case only, yes, for professional use of a scrubber in a visual editor, where, you *particularly need to* do the double-function I describe, very often.

Comment: This answer is full of excellent points, and the added images are great

Answer (score 4):

After reading some of the comments and answers and realising you want this button to skip to the start and start playing even if paused I realised maybe youre trying to invent a control that isnt necessarily needed by the majority of users (an assumption) and also would add more elements to the UI and potentially cause confusion and clutter.

From my experience when you are currently PAUSED and you use a skip control, the media will not automatically begin playing after skipping.

So an alternative idea is to offer an option in a settings area on your UI to turn auto play on/off. Therefore users that might benefit from the autoplay after skipping function can turn this on, and users that want a conventional skip and DON'T autoplay can have it turned off. And everyone gets to use a standard media playing UI without a brand new control that could cause confusion to some users if its unrecognisable.

### Example (in settings):

[image]

Comment: I definitely like this idea, and would normally do it, but, I'm saying that specifically in this editing suite, it's a fact that users commonly need both "Play" and "put head at start and also play with this one combined button" (and indeed a conventional "just return to start" button) ....

Answer (score 3):

To answer the keyboard UX question, HOME is often used to go to the beginning of a media clip. So then it would be HOME SPACE to skip to the beginning and play.

Comment: now that's bloody clever. however is there anything that is more one-time, maybe command-space??

Comment: Perhaps a function key? In windows, I might expect F5 or something. Not sure on OS X.

Comment: i would suggest alt + space on OS X

Answer (score 3):

I think that my idea may give you a little different view of this button.

Basically, my idea is very similar to the v1 of Chris Spittles's version, but the button should contain the progress bar (e.g. when you are around 50% of the progress, the button should look like in v2, but when you reach 90-95% of progress, it should look like in V1.

Of course, when you play the video, the progress bar "around" the rewind-and-play button should also be changing to mimic the current state of the progress bar. When the user notices the button for the first time, he/she may be a little confused but when he/she sees the button later, with a part of the circle around the play button, it should be very clear what is the function of the button. Plus, we get a nice "repeat" button at the end of the video :)

The "visual" part (all credits belong to Chris Spittles):

**50% of the playback:**

[image: 50% of playback]

**95% of the playback:**

[image: 95% of playback]

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I don't think I'd ever pick up on the subtleties of the arrow length without further explanation, and if further explanation is required anyways then it doesn't really matter what symbol you use.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the above or something similar to:

|->

"Start at the beginning and play."
Or:

[image]

Edit: I realize this could be interpreted in ways that you might not want.

Update: I did an image search on "play from beginning icon" and saw some of the samples from this page, but also an example using a bar like this:

[image]

Here the Play button could toggle between play and pause, while the first button will always play from the beginning.

These examples are from a set of icons called Diagona Icons
Copyright (C) 2007 Yusuke Kamiyamane but I did modify the "play from beginning" button to suit this example.

Comment: The turned _Eject_ symbol definitely has been used for this function, but in [Adobe Premiere Pro](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/playing-assets.html#jog_or_shuttle_playback) it actually means _Step Forward_.

Comment: Right - it's annoying that it suffers ambiguous usage.

Comment: It's a good thing no one piece of software is the definitive authority on icons and their meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Joining the brainstorm... I feel this should be more of a comment to some of the previous ideas. Borrowing from music notation and the general idea of the beginning of a score:

[image: G-key with trianlge]

Or, more correct maybe but less recognizable (Da capo):

[image: capo sign with triangle]

[ edit [

Or even with the 'real' note bar?

[image: capo sign with triangle and 5 lines]

In my opinion, the second one works strongest and connects best to previous ideas.

Comment: Wow.  What a clever idea.  Perhaps, should it be more like "start of the staff" (kind of like an E with five lines?)

Comment: It's almost as if musical notations were *made for this!*

Comment: I think the last item here is the most innovative on the page!

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>**[**►</kbd>

Opening bracket **[** for the beginning, ► for playing.

Also, there's a <kbd>Home</kbd> button on most keyboards that does what you'd expect.

Comment: Many video editors work on a mac, and most macs these days have the smaller keyboard that doesn't have a home button.

This of course may not be an important consideration for the software (Windows only environment, user demographics suggest that they have full-size keyboards etc.)

Comment: google says shortcut for Home key is Fn+←

Comment: man, that's a clever icon.

Comment: 100 points (to a new user right?) for an incredibly valuable suggestion.  Note too, RickHenderson's similar suggestion, also excellent.

Comment: it would be cool if some of the designers on here, or user13, edited in some "designy" versions of this!  it's an amazing idea to use the " [ " which is used in many contexts to mean back (eg, browsers) or "start of" as a general written concept.

Comment: @Fattie Not a new user, if you click my username and see all my network accounts, you'll get an idea what I'm about. Also, the `|►` symbol is used to denote "step forward" in old cassette players, which is like 1/5 of a second or however precise it is designed to step. And in digital players it means the next frame as per the video framerate. That's an already used symbol and it has the wrong connotation for the purpose of "from the beginning". Just something to remember.

Comment: new on this site, like me @user1306322 !  all understood, awesome

Answer (score 2):

The icon should visually represent the action(s) performed when clicked.

In this case, the action is:

1. Go Back (to the beginning)
2. Play (or continue playing)

The icon below is the most clear representaion of these two actions in sequence.

[image: Go Back and Play]

This shows 'go back' leading directly into 'play', and nothing following play. Other icons that do not show the connection and sequence could be interpreted as representing a different action - e.g. 'play then repeat'.

You should test this with your users. You might discover that they find the extra play buttons confusing, and prefer to click play, and then click the go-back-to-start button - because that is what they are used to when they operate a TV remote.

Comment: unfortunately, for me this icon *literally* means "go from where we are, to the end, then go to the beginning, then go to where we are now."

Comment: The design is evident to you but could have different interpretation. I think the main key here is you can try and make your design as intuitive as you can, but people are still going to need training.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply go to the basics? What you want exists since tape recorders and was used by most video players since the 70s (and even audio devices like walkman later): stop and pause/still buttons. Stop button sends you to beginning, pause/still button keeps you in place. No need to create icons, new affordances, anything, this is an at least 40 years old technology

[image]
[image]
[image]

This way, you only need a regular play button, and if anything, just highlight the "pause" button to denote position. Good proven old school design.

Comment: You know, I believe "Stop" does not snd you to the start on the VHS.  Great images!

Comment: you're correct, some of them did, some not, this is more a DVD thing due to the nature of digital "rewind". still the answer applies the same

Comment: 40 years old technology that users 25 years old or younger won't immediately understand.

Comment: So you're implying that tested and proven UX should be ditched for untested icons only because time passes by? If so, I gotta admit it's an extremely interesting and creative approach for sure. Btw, trigonometry works, but... You know, most 25 years and younger won't immediately understand it, maybe we should ditch that too, as we're at it ;)

Comment: @RickHenderson It's worth a test. It should be noted that "stop" to stop and go to the beginning, along with its associated symbol, is still being used by media players like VLC or Windows Media Player.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered a textual "Play from start" button?

Every one of the proposals here is worth conducting user testing on and collecting analytics for. If none prove to be adequately recognizable, a textual button might be the best solution.

Comment: I like text solutions for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I propose having three symbols.  If other action-symbols are appearing in buttons, then place all three of these symbols into a single button a button (a circle or (square) rectangle).

- A vertical line, and a left arrow (as seen in , [Kevin's answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/89766/77259), [Samuel Kelemen's answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/89800/77259))
- A comma
- A right arrow

This may be cramming things a bit, which could be counter-acted by using smaller symbols.  However, those downsides would be countered by the benefit of clarity of meaning.  Using these symbols is sort of like [ideogram's answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/89879/77259) but designed for people who can read and write paragraphs, not music notation.

Answer (score 1):

How about having a "bookmarks" panel, with a means of setting a particular bookmark as a default, and then having a "play bookmark" button on the scrubber control?  If there is a default bookmark at the start of the piece and no other bookmark is set, "play bookmark" would replay from start.  If, however, any other bookmark is set as the default, "play bookmark" would play from there.

Comment: I like it ! very nice..

Answer (score 1):

To answer your bonus question:

On Youtube, you can hit **0** and skip to the beginning of the video. If it's not playing already, but paused at some other point, you only need to slap **Space**. *The "regular" hotkeys don't work reliably every time because sometimes the browser focuses on the trackbar or you clicked the page, and the player isn't getting those key presses, so pressing Space might do a "page down" scroll instead. So press **K** to play/pause instead.*

In media players, if you have extra keys on your keyboard like Play/Pause, Stop, Next, Previous, like this for example:

[image]

…You can press **Stop** and then **Play**.

If you don't have those extra keys, media players usually understand pressing the **Home** key as "go to start".

So this is usually a 2-key job if you're paused, unless you're already playing.